# How do I get over the developper's moat?

Tags: candy-box

I keep just running into the moat and dying. Even with an invulnerability potion, I still die. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Become a Turtle

```
A turtle !
A turtle !
Do you want to     
become a turtle ?
```

Yes! The moat is actually crossable with a moving platform, but this platform moves too slowly for you. By becoming a turtle, you will move at the right speed to cross the moat. Drink it just before you're about to fall in, and your slower speed will match that of the platform.